# Get multiple JSON object array in single object array in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, codeigniter

I have created `json` array of result array in `php` I got following result:

```
[{
    "05-10-2018": "Seeing dads differently"
}, {
    "05-10-2018": "Extraordinary ordinary Britain"
}, {
    "05-10-2018": " Roll up for the Social Science Market!"
}, {
    "05-10-2018": "Why do we use it?"
}, {
    "05-10-2018": "Extraordinary ordinary Britain"
}]
```

But I want following format of result

```
{
    '12-14-2018': '<a href="http://google.com" target=_blank>Amet Temporibus ad quod enim dolor doloribus sequi!</a>',
    '09-30-2018': '<a href="http://google.com" target=_blank>Cupiditate blanditiis autem at obcaecati libero laborum.</a>',
    '09-22-2018': '<a href="http://google.com" target=_blank>Quo accusamus itaque esse aliquid error reprehenderit!</a>',
    '09-16-2018': '<a href="http://google.com" target=_blank>Quia magni aperiam nam asperiores animi enim?</a>',
    '08-21-2018': '<a href="http://google.com" target=_blank>Quia quibusdam nemo nobis rerum. Dolorem, ipsa?</a>',
    '08-09-2018': '<a href="http://google.com" target=_blank>At minima unde cum alias maiores corrupti quas.</a>',
    '07-23-2018': '<a href="http://google.com" target=_blank>Blanditiis maiores odio cumque eligendi facilis iure.</a>',
    '07-16-2018': '<a href="http://google.com" target=_blank>Dolorum, iusto quisquam distinctio dolore quo aperiam reiciendis.</a>',
    '06-28-2018': '<a href="http://google.com" target=_blank>Aperiam odio voluptatibus quae sunt unde itaque.</a>',
    '06-15-2018': '<a href="http://google.com" target=_blank>Tempore asperiores et possimus inventore vero ab.</a>',
    '06-02-2018': '<a href="http://google.com" target=_blank>Possimus asperiores perferendis recusandae debitis omnis consectetur aut!</a>',
    '05-30-2018': '<a href="http://google.com" target=_blank>Minus aliquid maxime atque praesentium rerum dolores sint?</a>',
    '05-18-2018': '<a href="http://google.com" target=_blank>Corporis accusantium assumenda facilis fugiat ut nostrum.</a>',
    '05-09-2018': '<a href="http://google.com" target=_blank>Sequi ad sint sunt quasi veniam cum.</a>',
};
```

How I get it?

Comment: What have you tried? And you want the code in `php` or `javascript`?

Comment: i have fetch array in php from database.but i want  following format
{
    '12-14-2018': '<a href="http://google.com" target=_blank>Amet Temporibus ad quod enim dolor doloribus sequi!</a>',
}; in jquery

Comment: Can you show the code where you get the data from the database as it may be possible to change that rather than do a second step.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [05-10-2018] => Seeing dads differently
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [05-10-2018] => Extraordinary ordinary Britain
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [05-10-2018] =>  Roll up for the Social Science Market!
        )

Comment: i want  following format in php 
{
    '12-14-2018': '<a href="http://google.com" target=_blank>Amet Temporibus ad quod enim dolor doloribus sequi!</a>',
    '09-30-2018': '<a href="http://google.com" target=_blank>Cupiditate blanditiis autem at obcaecati libero laborum.</a>',};

Answer (score -1):

try like this

```
$json = '[{"05-10-2018":"Seeing dads differently"},{"05-10-2018":"Extraordinary ordinary Britain"},{"05-10-2018":" Roll up for the Social Science Market!"},{"05-10-2018":"Why do we use it?"},{"05-10-2018":"Extraordinary ordinary Britain"}]';

$json_decoded = json_decode($json, true);
$results = array();
array_walk($json_decoded, function($v) use (&$results){
    $key = array_keys($v);
    $value = array_values($v);
    $results[] = "'{$key[0]}' : '<a href='http:www.google.com/' target='_blank'>{$value[0]}</a>'";
});
```

*output of **$results***

```
Array
(
    [0] => '05-10-2018' : '<a href='http:www.google.com/' target='_blank'>Seeing dads differently</a>'
    [1] => '05-10-2018' : '<a href='http:www.google.com/' target='_blank'>Extraordinary ordinary Britain</a>'
    [2] => '05-10-2018' : '<a href='http:www.google.com/' target='_blank'> Roll up for the Social Science Market!</a>'
    [3] => '05-10-2018' : '<a href='http:www.google.com/' target='_blank'>Why do we use it?</a>'
    [4] => '05-10-2018' : '<a href='http:www.google.com/' target='_blank'>Extraordinary ordinary Britain</a>'
)
```

*output of **$result_code***

```
$result_code = '{'.implode(',', $results).'}';

{
'05-10-2018' : '<a href='http:www.google.com/' target='_blank'>Seeing dads differently</a>',
'05-10-2018' : '<a href='http:www.google.com/' target='_blank'>Extraordinary ordinary Britain</a>',
'05-10-2018' : '<a href='http:www.google.com/' target='_blank'> Roll up for the Social Science Market!</a>',
'05-10-2018' : '<a href='http:www.google.com/' target='_blank'>Why do we use it?</a>',
'05-10-2018' : '<a href='http:www.google.com/' target='_blank'>Extraordinary ordinary Britain</a>'
}
```